# fdisk vs. vgdisplay - increase size of VG

Tags: fdisk

After getting error messages that I was running out of disk space, I looked at the disks and found that the output from fdisk (**127.101 GiB**) did not coincide with the output from vgdisplay (**57.43 GiB**).

How can I allocate the full disk space to the VG?

Anyone some suggestions?

Please help.

Thank you!

**Output *fdisk -l***

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-1d8a72d1-87d4-4c04-8a21-20a63699b4b8: **127.101 GiB**, 137422176256 bytes, 268402688 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

**Output *vgdisplay***

Disk /dev/loop4: 455.56 MiB, 477675520 bytes, 932960 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

--- Volume group ---

VG Name               qubes_dom0

System ID

Format                lvm2

Metadata Areas        1

Metadata Sequence No  135

VG Access             read/write

VG Status             resizable

MAX LV                0

Cur LV                39

Open LV               11

Max PV                0

Cur PV                1

Act PV                1

VG Size               **57.43 GiB**

PE Size               4.00 MiB

Total PE              14703

Alloc PE / Size       11765 / <45.96 GiB

Free  PE / Size       2938 / <11.48 GiB

VG UUID               LHX4Ra-a4Io-X5Lj-2JfQ-A7Vf-tUni-gz4L29

Comment: Please add here output of `pvs` and `lsblk`. Did you resize your disk and/or the LUKS device recently?

Comment: if a simple pvresize does not fix it, please post readable output...

Comment: Please edit your post to show the commands and the output as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding.
I ended up reinstalling the whole system from scratch, and the problem has been solved.
Something was wrong on the initial installation, but unfortunately I´ll never discover it.
Anyway, thank you very much for the suggestions and support!